# Why does this glsl shader not respect the depth index?

Tags: glsl, shader

This is a vertex shader I'm currently working with:

```
attribute vec3 v_pos;
attribute vec4 v_color;
attribute vec2 v_uv;
attribute vec3 v_rotation; // [angle, x, y]

uniform mat4 modelview_mat;
uniform mat4 projection_mat;

varying vec4 frag_color;
varying vec2 uv_vec;
varying mat4 v_rotationMatrix;

void main (void) {

    float cos = cos(v_rotation[0]);
    float sin = sin(v_rotation[0]);

    mat2 trans_rotate = mat2(
      cos, -sin,
      sin, cos
    );

    vec2 rotated = trans_rotate * vec2(v_pos[0] - v_rotation[1], v_pos[1] - v_rotation[2]);
    gl_Position = projection_mat * modelview_mat * vec4(rotated[0] + v_rotation[1], rotated[1] + v_rotation[2], 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position[2] = 1.0 - v_pos[2] / 100.0; // Arbitrary maximum depth for this shader.
    frag_color = vec4(gl_Position[2], 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // <----------- !!
    uv_vec = v_uv;
}
```

and the fragment:

```
varying vec4 frag_color;
varying vec2 uv_vec;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main (void){
    vec4 color = texture2D(tex, uv_vec) * frag_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Notice how I'm manually setting the Z index of the gl_Position variable to be a bound value in the range 0.0 -> 1.0 (the upper bound is done in code; safe to say, not vertex has a z value < 0 or > 100).

It works... mostly. The problem is that when I render it, I get this:

[image]

That's not the correct depth sorting for these elements, which have z value respectively, of 15, 50 and 80, as you can see from the red value for each sprite.

The correct order to render in would be blue -> top, purple middle, and pink bottom; but instead these sprites are being rendered in *render order*.

ie. They are being drawn via:

```
glDrawArrays() <--- Pink, first geometry batch
glDrawArrays() <--- Blue, second geometry batch
glDrawArrays() <--- Purple, thirds geometry batch
```

What's going on?

Surely it irrelevant how many times I call gl draw functions before flushing; the depth testing should sort this all out right?

Do you have to manually invoke depth testing inside the fragment shader somehow?

Comment: Z index? To me, calling it that implies something a lot different (an integer vector). But I guess since you are using array subscript notation instead of the more common swizzle notation (e.g. `[2]` instead of `.z`) you think of it the way you do. I would consider calling it the `z` **component** or `3rd` **component** (instead of **index**) for clarity. In any event, are you using perspective projection? You should divide your red component by `W` if you are, so that it will match the post-perspective depth.

Comment: Correct, it's the z coordinate, not the z index; I used that name simply because this is an orthographic projection, and the z values take discrete integer values; however, they *are* passed as float values in the z component of the interleaved array (vec3 v_pos). As the diagram shows, the red component is being correctly rendered as the depth on the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're normalizing the output Z value into the range: **0.0** - **1.0**?

It should really be the range: **-W** - **+W**. Given an orthographic projection, this means the clip-space Z should range from: **-1.0** - **+1.0**. You are only using half of your depth range, which reduces the resolving capability of the depth buffer significantly.

To make matters worse (and I am pretty sure this is where your actual problem comes from) it looks like you are inverting your depth buffer by giving the farthest points a value of **0.0** and the nearest points **1.0**. In actuality, **-1.0** corresponds to the near plane and **1.0** corresponds to the far plane in OpenGL.

```c
gl_Position[2] = 1.0 - v_pos[2] / 100.0;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// This needs to be changed, your depth is completely backwards.


gl_Position.z = 2.0 * (v_pos.z / 100.0) - 1.0;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// This should fix both the direction, and use the full depth range.
```

However, it is worth mentioning that now the value of `gl_Position[2]` or `gl_Position.z` ranges from **-1.0** to **1.0** which means it cannot be used as a visible color without some scaling and biasing:

```c
frag_color = vec4 (gl_Position.z * 0.5 + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // <----------- !!
```

On a final note, I have been discussing **Normalized Device Coordinates** this entire time, not window coordinates. In window coordinates the default depth range is 0.0 = near, 1.0 = far; this may have been the source of some confusion. Understand that window coordinates (`gl_FragCoord`) are not pertinent to the calculations in the vertex shader.

#### You can use this in your fragment shader to test if your depth range is setup correctly:

```c
vec4 color = texture2D(tex, uv_vec) * vec4 (gl_FragCoord.z, frag_color.yzw);
```

It should produce the same results as:

```c
vec4 color = texture2D(tex, uv_vec) * frag_color;
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this is actually correct. Using: gl_Position[2] = -1.0 + v_pos[2] / 50.0; made them render in correct depth order. Totally weird as far as I'm concerned though; the difference between using half the depth range and the whole depth range makes a difference? I don't really understand. ...but it worked, so thanks!

Comment: @Doug: Well it's a combination of the two things really, you are using the depth buffer in the proper direction with change you posted, and also using the full range of the depth buffer. The thing about storing depth in the proper direction is almost certainly what fixed it.